# i want to delete only 1st no and "," in MySQL. ex (2,14,20,15) ==> (14,10,15)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like the following:

```
foo  |  bar  |  up_tag                       
---------------------------            
 2   |  b    |  2,14,20                       
 5   |  a    |  3,16,20
```

I want to update the up_tag column so that the first number and first comma are removed. So 2,14,20 would become 14,20. All other columns must remain the same. On the example above the desired output is :

```
foo  |  bar  |  up_tag                       
---------------------------            
 2   |  b    |  14,20                       
 5   |  a    |  16,20
```

Comment: Elaborate more. It is unclear what you are asking

Comment: Please add further information

Comment: can you explain what your problem is?

Comment: Survey, pls fill: I've tried the query .... but I faced the problem ... . During my research, I found out, that ...., but I have a problem to fully understand or apply the knowledge. Please direct me in the right direction. So far, I know, that the solution with ... or with ... or the one with ... don't work for me because ....

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this cause i am running on MSSQL but in fact of MySQL documentation this should be query for you

`SELECT SUBSTRING(UP_TO, LOCATE(',',UP_TO)+1) FROM YourTableName`

It should locate first occurrence of '**,**' character a then return substring from it's possition.

Comment: ya its work..!!! thank you

Comment: this is select query.this return me only up_tag but i want to complete table..so plz give me any update query.

Comment: Well in case of update just update the value by the new, selected value so: UPDATE YourTable SET UP_TO = SUBSTRING(UP_TO, LOCATE(',',UP_TO)+1)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE your_table_name
SET up_tag=SUBSTRING(up_tag, LOCATE(',', up_tag) + 1);
```